# Setup cron job to execute python script inside the bash sh file

Tags: bash, cron, sh

I did create a Cron job to run the bash file, it went OK from command line, but if running from the Cron job, it gave me error saying "Python is not a command"

My bash file called: Myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/public_html/test_scripts
python script1.py serverlog.log 2&>1 &
python script2.py serverlog.log 2&>1 &
```

My cron job setting

```
30 5 * * 1-5 root bash Myscript.sh
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and to get around this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Is PATH set appropriately in the crontab file?

Comment: Yes, the path is set correctly to put to the location of Myscript.sh

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the full path to python. If you don't know path, you can find it with `which` command:

```
➜  ~ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

and then modify your script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/public_html/test_scripts
/usr/bin/python script1.py serverlog.log 2&>1 &
/usr/bin/python script2.py serverlog.log 2&>1 &
```

Comment: Hi,  After putting the full path to the Python interpreter, the error message was gone, but now it complains about some modules are not found when running from Cron, but if run from command line, then all good. Anyone know why?

Comment: similar quesion was here, please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970905/cannot-import-python-mysql-module-when-running-a-script-using-crontab