# crontab failing to use anaconda python even after adding path (cron calls .sh file which in turn calls .py file)

Tags: python, shell, cron, anaconda

I have a cronjob:

```
1 11 * * * /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python /home/ubuntu/ga_data/gaV4/tva_gaApiUpdate.sh > /dev/null 2 >> tvaUpdater.log
```

And here is the .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/ga_data/gaV4
python gaAPIWorkingVersion.py
echo "ran cron at" | tee -a  "$tvaUpdater.log"
echo $(date) | tee -a  "$tvaUpdater.log"
```

The output of the log file is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gaAPIWorkingVersion.py", line 13, in <module>
    from apiclient.discovery import build
ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery
```

I'm calling a .sh file with cron that in turn calls a .py file. I do this because in the .sh file I change directory with cd, so that I don't have to change paths within my .py script to absolute paths. This is because my larger .py script opens several files from within it's directory. So, rather than call python directly in the cron I do so indirectly by calling the .sh file first.

When I run the .sh or .py script directly myself, everything works. It's only when cron tries to do so that I get the error above.

If I go `which python` in the terminal I get `/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python`.

I tried adding that line into my .sh file like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/ga_data/gaV4
python /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python gaAPIWorkingVersion.py
```

But that also threw an error.

How can I get cron to use the right version of python (anaconda in this case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your cron to:

```
1 11 * * * /home/ubuntu/ga_data/gaV4/tva_gaApiUpdate.sh > /dev/null 2 >> tvaUpdater.log
```

and script to

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/ga_data/gaV4
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python gaAPIWorkingVersion.py
echo "ran cron at" | tee -a  "$tvaUpdater.log"
echo $(date) | tee -a  "$tvaUpdater.log"
```

Make sure that user under which scipt is running directly is same as the one of cronjob.
If you still have problems, check [Cannot Import Python MySQL module when running a script using crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970905/cannot-import-python-mysql-module-when-running-a-script-using-crontab)